# Clarification about the toString method within an ADT class

Tags: java, tostring

This is the modified toString function within the Complex ADT class that i'm trying to implement (My doubt is only regarding this function so I havent included the private variables declared before and the other functions) :

```
class ComplexCart implements Complex{
  public String toString(){
    if(image == 0) return (real + "");
  }
}
```

Why can't we write the following?

```
if(imag == 0) return(real);
```

Why do we need to add the additional  **""**  ?

Answer (score 0):

since the return type is `String`, and real is integer type. alternatively you can use `real.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

```
 public String toString(){
    if(image == 0) return (real + "");
  }
```

In the above code if `real`  is not of type `String`  it's `compile time error`.

if it is of type `String`.No errorrs occures.

To make `real` as `string` you are writing `real + "".`

Then , Immediate question is Then how it's working with `+ ""`  ??

Here the [Docs of String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

> The Java language provides special support for the string concatenation operator ( + ), and for conversion of other objects to strings. String concatenation is implemented through the StringBuilder(or StringBuffer) class and its append method. String conversions are implemented through the method toString, defined by Object and inherited by all classes in Java.

**As a side note:**

concatenating with String is a bad idea.There are some identical and better ways to do it.

```
1)Integer.toString(intval);
2)String.valueOf(intval);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!real is an "int" type.

Comment: What you have linked is not the language specification, it's the documentation of the `String` class.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have to return a `String` from `toString()`, and presumably `real` is not a `String`. `real + ""` performs string concatenation (converting `real` to a `String` and concatenating it with the empty string; see [JLS §15.18.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)) and results in a `String`, which is why you can validly return it.

Note that you should consider using something like `Integer.toString(real)` over `real + ""` (see [`Integer.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int%29)).

Answer (score 0):

Since `real` is int type where as `toString()` method expects String to return.So you need add `""`;
`+` is String concatenation operator here.